# Entity classes not inheriting from correct base class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance

I am using EF 6.0 in my application. My problem is simple but it still had me scratching my head.I am creating partial classes corresponding to the entity classes to implement some custom properties there in.

Since i am using EF 6, i am inheriting my implementation of the partial class from `System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject`
But when i update the model from the DB, the auto generated designer file has all the partial entity classes inheriting from `System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject`. This is throwing compile time error "Partial declarations of 'EMS.DAL.Category' must not specify different base classes". 'Category' being the partial entity class.

Any pointers please about whats wrong, missing references or what?

Comment: If my understanding is correct EMS.DAL.Category should have a class name Category.Please check you have overridden with your Partial class,I mean Give the Partial Class name(Generated by System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject)in Category Class and Compile.

Comment: Do not specify the base class in your partial custom class, only the extra things (an interface, properties, methods, etc).

Comment: @Maarten will that still enable me utilizing the EF 6, because the application was upgraded to this from EF 4 as part of performance optimization?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EF6 you need to use EF6 tooling. It is included in VS2013 but there is also a version EF6 tooling available for [download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762) for VS2012. If you use old tooling with EF6 you will end up having some intricate and hard to resolve issues because of changes to EF6 runtime. Here is a [blog post](http://blog.3d-logic.com/2013/11/10/what-changed-in-the-ef-tooling-in-visual-studio-2013-and-visual-studio-2012-out-of-band/) I wrote on this topic.